# How to pass a PEM cert/key as variable to a node.js project

Tags: javascript, variables, node.js, pem

I am trying to set up an Apple Push Notification service with node-apn. I have written the other parts of the project (RESTful API, backend, message queueing) but I run into a blocking problem with the node.js portion.

I have to pass node-apn a key and a certificate and this is normally done passing a pair of filenames as option to it. However this setup is not ideal and I need to pass them as variables. I have already changed node-aps' source and it would happily look for these variables if it wasn't for an issue I didn't considerate while studying a solution.

Javascript doesn't accept multiline variables so I can't pass a certificate or a key in this format:

```
var cert = '-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
[cut]
-----END CERTIFICATE-----';
```

I tried escaping newlines with \ but then I end up with a one line certificate/key and so I get a "PEM_read_bio:no start line" error.

Is there any decent workaround?

Comment: Find out any more detail on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can have newlines in your string like this:

```
var cert = '-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n\
[cut]\n\
-----END CERTIFICATE-----';
```

But I think that it's a better idea to put your certificate files separately. Above code doesn't look ideal in my opinion.